# Conditional string concatenation

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to rearrange strings in a data frame column, however not all the entries need rearranging.  For example I'd like each name in the following data frame to be in a 'FirstName LastName' order.  Some of the names are already in this format (e.g. Jim Beam), others are not (i.e. the ones with a comma), and some just have one name (e.g. Plague).

```
class_list = pd.DataFrame({'names':['Chinit, Janine', 'Plague', 'Leggit, Marjorie', 'Jim Beam']})
```

I am able use the following to successfully rearrange the names with commas, however the single names or those that don't need rearranging are lost in the process.

```
name_list = class_list.names
names = name_list.str.split(',', expand = True)
names_fixed = names[1] + ' ' + names[0]
names_fixed
```

How do I add a conditional statement to the above to only rearrange those names that have a comma?  This is what I'd like the output to be:

```
names_fixed = pd.DataFrame({'names':['Janine Chinit', 'Plague', 'Marjorie Leggit', 'Jim Beam']})
```

In my actual use case I have >300k records that need this treatment, so a computationally efficient solution is required.

Thanks in advance,
-Rameses

Comment: can you please write desired output

Comment: desired output added to original question.  Thanks for pointing this out @Akhilesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class_list['names_fixed'] = class_list.names.apply(lambda x: x.split(",")[1] + " " + x.split(",")[0] if "," in x else x)
```

applying `lambda` function with condition `if "," in x` then `x.split` with `separator` '`,'`  which will make a `list` and `concatenating` `[1]` and `[0]` element of `list` with `" "`   and  `else` taking `x` only

for more `apply` check this link [https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html][1]

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it